# Why is this odd 3 wire light not working?

Tags: wiring, lighting, light-fixture

I have a very odd light problem. We took down the ceiling to move a light. We have two switches in the dining room that control two lights. After moving the one light, I tested the light I moved and it is working fine. I simply physically moved the box, I didn't do any new wiring. I'm not sure I tested the other light but it was working before the ceiling came down. Now, the light I moved is working but the other light doesn't come on. The odd thing is that the working light is getting power from the non-working light.

Another odd thing is that the non working light has odd wiring in that there are two white wires coming out of each cable but no ground wire. One of these white wires seems thicker and is partially stripped at the base. The working light has regular two-wire with ground.

Why would this light not be working?

[image: Current light]

[image: Light before removal]

[image: Switch closet to non-working light]

Comment: "I simply physically moved the box, I didn't do any new wiring"  --- It would be very odd if you could move a box without doing any wiring.  can you explain what you mean by move a box ?

Comment: @Alaska man What I mean is that I didn't run any new cable, I just used the existing old cable.

Comment: FYI- none of this is odd, you've got a bad connection or mis-wire.  We also need to see how the switch is wired and what colors are there too help you sort this out.  The 3-wire connection is likely for the switch loop from what we know now....

Comment: Do you mean you just scooched the box over, dragging the cables as they were originally attached, and didn't unbolt any cable clamps? That cable clamp looks unbolted.

Comment: It looks to me like the foremost white wires in your first photo have had a bit of white sheath shoved over them, and I suspect they were originally the *ground* wires.  Some guy needed /3 cable but didn't want to pay for it, so he "improvised".  Assume the person is cheap but not stupid, that will be the neutral (bold assumption).  If you bought the house recently I'd raise the issue with your home warranty insurer, they owe you a box-by-box electrical inspection and repair, and they ought to go recover from the seller.

Comment: @Harper that's it then. The ground in the working box is actually a neutral that needs to be tied with the other neural? The ground line going to the first switch is also neutral?

But according to this image. I should be able to make the two sheathed lines ground and it should fix it and work.
[3 Way Switch Wiring Diagram](https://www.easy-do-it-yourself-home-improvements.com/images/xLarge-3-way-switch-9.jpg.pagespeed.ic.bhEF6j6awd.jpg)

Comment: The loose black and white wire in the top photo surely go to the lamp. Lamps need neutral. So presumably the white loose wire goes into the neutral bundle with those "gypsy neutrals", which would validate they are indeed neutral.  I would still hit them with a voltage tester, just to be sure, the stupid is strong with "the last guy".

Comment: I'm a little cautious to say "it'll just work" because obviously the guy ran the neutral *for a reason* i.e. he needed one more wire.  Anytime you're in a 3-way circuit it can get a little complicated because it is almost impossible to keep track of which *color* wire has which *function*.  Therefore I am fastidious about using colored tape, and I [redrew that drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxKJA.png) to color for function.  Yellow are the two travelers which land on brass screws, always color both ends of a wire at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The existing wiring is as in this diagram:

[image]

So the solution was to tie the white sheathed wires with a copper wire to make them ground again. I tied in another black to the existing blacks (one was cut off previously for some reason) and hooked the black and "white" (black wire tied in with the other whites) to the light. All works fine now.

Comment: No, you shouldn't do that -- that's a good way to get zapped!

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel How so?

Comment: Now you have current flowing through ground wires, which puts anything connected to them "live"

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel No, the ground wires are all ground again exactly as they should be.

Comment: Can you explain what's going on more clearly then please?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel the jerry-rigged "neutral" wire in the light box was tied in with the other grounds in the switch box. This was probably changed by an electrician previously who found the original configuration unsafe.